# how to recall variable in foreach Loop C#

Tags: c#, foreach

I'm new to C#. I wrote a foreach loop,but how can I recall the variables outside the loop. Thanks for your help.

Here is my code:

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
   IDictionary<string,float> IDico=new Dictionary<string,float>();
   IDico.Add("D1",1);
   IDico.Add("D2",2);
   IDico.Add("D3",3);

   string tempo="D2";

   foreach(var element in IDico.Keys)
   {
    if(tempo.Contains(element in IDico.Keys)
     {
       var outPut=IDico[element]
     }
   }
   var call=outPut // How can I call outPut outside the for loop?Because the outPut doesn't exist for this row.

}
```

Comment: Declare it outside the loop and assign it inside. In order to do that though, you'll need to use the concrete type instead of `var`.

Comment: you mean  I define float outPut outside the loop ,outPut=IDico[element] and I can call at the end?

Comment: still an error:Use of unassigned local variable outPut

Comment: You have to initialize it when you create it, `float outPut = 0.0f;` then you can use it.

Comment: @ Ron Beyer Thanks for your help. It works

Answer (score 3):

This is your code

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
   IDictionary<string,float> IDico=new Dictionary<string,float>();
   IDico.Add("D1",1);
   IDico.Add("D2",2);
   IDico.Add("D3",3);

   string tempo="D2";
   float outPut = 0.0;
   foreach(var element in IDico.Keys)
   {
    if(tempo.Contains(element))
     {
       outPut=IDico[element]
     }
   }
    //Do stuff with outPut
}
```

however i think you may be trying to find tempo in the dictionary so really you should just do this:

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
   IDictionary<string,float> IDico=new Dictionary<string,float>();
   IDico.Add("D1",1);
   IDico.Add("D2",2);
   IDico.Add("D3",3);

   string tempo="D2";
   float outPut = 0.0;
   if(IDico.Contains(tempo))
     {
       outPut=IDico[tempo];
     }
   //Do stuff with outPut
 }
```

Comment: could you explain the part if(tempo.Contains(element in IDico.Keys) because I don't understand why you use two time. And I  still have an error:Use of unassigned local variable outPut

Comment: If `IDico` had some entry having value of `0f`, the `output` here would possibly be ambiguous about the value source it gets: from its initialization or from some entry of `IDico`? It should be better to declare `float?` for output. Then check if it is not null to process more.

Comment: Updated my answer, i'm not to sure what is trying to be achieved from the question.

Comment: @ZachM. You're right. The version2.0 is better. Thanks for your help

Comment: Nice find, outPut is still declared inside the if-statement though and can't be accessed outside of it.

Comment: Derp fixed, meant to copy that over.

Answer (score 0):

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
   IDictionary<string,float> IDico=new Dictionary<string,float>();
   IDico.Add("D1",1);
   IDico.Add("D2",2);
   IDico.Add("D3",3);

   string tempo="D2";
   string outPut = string.Empty;

   foreach(var element in IDico.Keys)
   {
       if(tempo.Contains(element))
       {
           outPut = IDico[element]
       }
   }

   var call = outPut;
}
```

If outPut can contain more than one element from your dictionary consider using and array or list. If you want to stop iterating after you find a match use a break; in the if statement so that after the match is found the loop will stop.

Also, you're going to want to declare outPut outside of loop so it doesn't re declare itself on each iteration of the loop.

I also fixed the contains statement for you as well as you were using improper syntax.